# grep match with following lines that start with whitespace

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep

### The Problem

Let's say I have a file with the following content:

```
lmtp_bind_address (default: empty)
       The LMTP-specific version of the smtp_bind_address configuration parameter.  See there for details.

       This feature is available in Postfix 2.3 and later.

lmtp_bind_address6 (default: empty)
       The LMTP-specific version of the smtp_bind_address6 configuration parameter.  See there for details.

       This feature is available in Postfix 2.3 and later.

lmtp_body_checks (default: empty)
       The LMTP-specific version of the smtp_body_checks configuration parameter. See there for details.

       This feature is available in Postfix 2.5 and later.
```

I want to get the line starting with "lmtp_bind_address6" and all following lines that start with a whitespace:

```
lmtp_bind_address6 (default: empty)
       The LMTP-specific version of the smtp_bind_address6 configuration parameter.  See there for details.

       This feature is available in Postfix 2.3 and later.
```

**How can I do this in bash?**

### Background Info

I am moving away from Centos 7 and am setting up Postfix on Debian 8. Therefore, I intend to read the "man 5 postconf" which is 7255 lines long as of Postfix version 2.11.3. In order to speed thing up I want to group Postfix options in the manpage that cover the same thing but for different protocols such as:

```
smtpd_tls_mandatory_ciphers
lmtp_tls_mandatory_ciphers
smtp_tls_mandatory_ciphers
tlsproxy_tls_mandatory_ciphers
```

As you can see up above, each of these four options makes it possible to select the TLS ciphers, but for different protocols (SMTPD, LMTP etc.).

First, I grouped the Postfix options the following way:

```
postconf | awk -F"=" '{print $1}' | sed 's/ //g' | rev | sort | \
rev > postconf_options.txt
```

Then, I dumped the manpage to a file:

```
man 5 postconf > postconf_manpage.txt
```

Now, I want to go through the grouped list and dump every match with the following lines, that start with a whitespace, to a third file:

```
cat postconf_options.txt | while read I; do
  grep -w "^$I" postconf_manpage.txt
done > postconf_manpage_grouped.txt
```

The above grep command just gives out the line with the match, but not the following lines starting with a whitespace.

### Solution

I used double quotes with sed in order to be able to use variables. Here is the complete procedure with the solution from [hek2mgl](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38203090/2486134):

```
postconf | awk -F"=" '{print $1}' | sed 's/ //g' | rev | sort | rev > postconf_options.txt
man 5 postconf > postconf_manpage.txt
cat postconf_options.txt | while read I; do sed -n "/^$I/{p;:a;n;/^[[:space:]]\|^$/{p;ba}}" postconf_manpage.txt; done > postconf_manpage_grouped.txt
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use `sed`:

```
sed -n '/^lmtp_bind_address6/{p;:a;n;/^[[:space:]]\|^$/{p;ba}}' file
```

- `/^lmtp_bind_address6/` matches the search pattern
- `{p;:a;n;/^[[:space:]]\|^$/{p;ba}}` does print the line using `p`, defines a label `:a` which acts as a jump-mark to be able to iterate over lines starting with a space. `n` will read another line into the pattern buffer. `/^[[:space:]]\|^$/` matches a line that starts with a space **or** an empty line. If that's the case the line will get printed using `p` and we'll jump back to `a` using `ba`.

Comment: Nice and this doesn't assume `lmtp_` as a record separator too. :)

Comment: Your forgot "^": `sed -n '/^lmtp_bind_address6/{p;:a;n;/^[[:space:]]\|^$/{p;ba}}'`

Comment: @user2486134 Added that

Comment: Excellent solution, but it has a flaw. If you want to catch all blocks with lmtp_bind_address6 and have two consecutive ones, the second one is skipped. That is IMHO due to the "n" already skipped the line into pattern buffer, before it is checked to start with spaces, so it might be the one having lmtp_bind_address6 again, so after escape from first match it is already gone. Not sure how to skip one line back, like a reverse "n" after exiting a match, but that should be doable.
Catched it when my logfile had 5 error messages while sed gave me only 4.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to get the line starting with "lmtp_bind_address6" and all following lines that start with a whitespace

You can use this awk:

```
awk 'p && /^[^[:blank:]]/{p=0} /^lmtp_bind_address6/{p=1} p' file

lmtp_bind_address6 (default: empty)
       The LMTP-specific version of the smtp_bind_address6 configuration parameter.  See there for details.

       This feature is available in Postfix 2.3 and later.
```

- `/^lmtp_bind_address6/{p=1}` sets `p=1` when desired pattern is found at line start
- `p && /^[^[:blank:]]/{p=0}` resets `p=0` when `p` is set and when a non-blank character is found at line start.